# Expose Typescript type declarations for untyped package

Tags: typescript, build

I'm using an untyped (commonJS) external package to build my library. Therefore, I created a `.d.ts` file to add those typings. However, these type declarations are not carried over to in my output bundle. How can I assure that they get bundled in my library so that the consumer gets properly typed components?

```js
// untyped package => ./src/types/untypedPackage.d.ts;

declare module "untyped-package" {
   // type declarations here
}
```

I've read that I probably need to use a triple-slash directive on the consumer end, but I also read that it's not a good practice. What's the best way to make this automatic without fiddling with triple-slash directives or copying .d.ts files + to build folder + re-importing them in the consumer project?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the types in `/src`! Many libraries just put it in the root folder. So you won't need to copy it over, but make sure to set [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) in the tsconfig file.

Comment: Doing that will allow the consumer to automatically have type definitions for that untyped external package?

Comment: I think yes. Maybe you also need to add a `typings` field to the package.json, pointing to that folder. If you want to try it, just make a new node project and run `npm install ../path/to/main/project`